# Submit Link for a contact form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, submit

First off, I have searched an searched this site for answers but every code I came across seems to be so different what I have that I can't seem to find one that fits my problem.

Having that said, here is my issue:

I am trying to have a contact form on my site that will submit a form to an email, pretty basic I thought... it works fine if I do it as its own code on a blank test page, opening up the php file and submitting, as far as i know. But when I put the code onto the styled site it fails to do anything.

Ultimately I would like have it simply go to a success page when I click submit but I am working on getting the submitting to work correctly first. Here is the code I have for the submit form:

```
     <form id="form1" action="send_mail.php" method="post">
             <div class="success"> 
             <div class="success_txt"> 
               Contact form submitted!<br><strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong> 
             </div>
             </div>
                 <fieldset>
                     <span class="form_label">Name:</span>
                     <label class="name">
                     <input type="text" value="" name="cf_name">
                     <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>
                        <br>
                     <span class="form_label">E-mail:</span>
                     <label class="email">
                     <input type="text" value="" name="cf_email">
                     <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>
                     <br>
                     <span class="form_label">Phone:</span>
                     <label class="phone">
                     <input type="tel" value="" name="cf_phone">
                     <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span><!--<span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>--> </label>
                                    <br>
                     <span class="form_label">Message:</span>
                     <label class="message"> 
                     <textarea></textarea>
                     <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span><span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>
                               <br>
                    <div class="btns right"><a href="#" class="more" data-type="reset"><span></span>clear</a><a href="send_mail.php" class="more" data-type="submit"><span></span>submit</a></div>
              </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Also I was searching around I read here: [Submit button for my contact form is not submitting and redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270729/submit-button-for-my-contact-form-is-not-submitting-and-redirecting)
about cleaning the imputed text prior to sending? Can anyone touch on that? and if I just basically place the code shown in mine with changed variables is that all I need to do or is it more involved than that?

Thanks so much for reading this and any help is definitely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a html form. So you can submit the input type values to the action page **send_mail.php** using Submit button.

Use

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

instead of the submit link. This will submit your form and you can access all input values in that page and can add code for sending mail there. After successful submission in send_mail.php page, redirect to the action page(the page with the submit button) with a parameter, for example write code as following in send_mail.php page,

```
header("location:actionpage.php?message=sucess");
exit;
```

And in the action page check whether the message exists or not.

```
 <div class="success_txt"> 
<?php if(isset($_GET['message']))
{?>php
               Contact form submitted!<br><strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong> 
<?php } ?>
             </div>
```

Comment: Ok, so what you're saying is that if I use a button instead it will work and all I need to do is have the send_mail switch message to success so that the HTML page will know to switch to a "successfully sent" page or a "failed to send" page?

Comment: all you want is to show a success or fail message upon submission right?

Comment: Ya. Basically, just switch page to show "Your message has been sent successfully.ok, and I changed the code in the HTML file to: `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` rather than: `<a href="#" class="more" data-type="submit">Submit</a>` but when i click it nothing seems to be doing anything? Is there a possibility that the webpage its on could be messing with the code and how it works? Because like I said earlier I could get it to work when I just did it on a test page?